# Bash get string after running command in terminal

Tags: regex, bash, shell

In bash i have a string like this, please notice the first line and last line is blank.

How can i get the 300 number and the 20 number?

```
#first blank line

Found 300 modems:
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/20 [huawei] E3131
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [huawei] E3131
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [huawei] E303

#last blank line
```

Comment: Have you tried awk yet?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl version...

```
perl -ne 'if(m[Found (\d+)] || m[Modem/(\d+)]) {print "$1\n"}' < file_name
```

Note. You can use the following script top play with the regex...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
  if(m[Found (\d+)] || m[Modem/(\d+)]) {
    print "$1 \n";
  }
}
__DATA__
#first blank line

Found 300 modems:
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/20 [huawei] E3131
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [huawei] E3131
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [huawei] E303

#last blank line
```

If you save that script as `test.pl` you can use it like this...

```
perl -ne 'if(m[Found (\d+)] || m[Modem/(\d+)]) {print "$1\n"}' < test.pl
```

and I got the following output...

```
300
20
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have that output stored in a variable called `${var}`, you can do

```
sed -n 's/Found \([0-9]*\) modems:/\1/p' <<< "${var}"
```

`sed` loops over all lines in the string, `-n` suppresses the output. If we find the line with `Found n modems:`, we substitute it with the number only (`s` command) and print the line (`p` flag).

Comment: I think he made it clear 300 and 20, your code only prints 300

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I leave that as an exercise. :-P

Comment: Oh i see, now that's one hell of excuse.

Comment: Can you please show me how to get the second number 20 please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will print 300, 20, 1, and 0:

```
sed -ne 's/Found \(.*\) modems:/\1/p' -e 's:.*Modem/\([^ ]*\) .*:\1:p' FILENAME
```

`-n` says not to print the output by default
`-e COMMAND` executes COMMAND. You can use it more than once.
Ending the `s` command with `p` says to print if any substitution happens.

Run `man sed` for more information.

If you really only want 300 and 20 as output, append `|head -2` to limit the output to the first two lines.